# How can I generate a software update package?

Tags: updates, liquibase

I am searching for a peace of software that permit me to build a package that will perform update of already delivered software.

Because I am using [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/), I am searching something that would work a little bit like Liquibase.

I think this software, may need to be configured be providing it what actions have to be done for updating from version X-1 to version X.

And the package will be an aggregation of every steps, and by detecting that the version X-t is installed, it will then need to execute t actions to make the update to version X.

I know that StackOverflow is not meant to answer to this kind of questions, but I don't really know how are named this kind of software nor where to search for it.

If this can run on Linux and Windows it would be great.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me, but I have tried my best to give you an answer that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds a lot like what a **package manager** does. Some of them support [delta updates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_update).

Answer (score 0):

By the problem definition it sounds like you need to create installation packages.
For the windows platform have a look at [WiX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX/), - it covers all possible needs, and imho is the best of its class. But has a bit steep learning curve. 
Another fair windows alternative is [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) - way easier, but not so mighty.

I am not familiar with an installer framework which can do for both Linux and Windows.

If you are totally new in the field, [this](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Installers) is a good point to start digging from.

Answer (score 0):

I am using "Setup Factory" for this porpose,
You can create patches and you cand create updates.